# GSON - How can I parse two JSONArrays with the same name, but different parameters?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

In the Reddit JSON API, comments can contain two different types of JSONArrays, both called "children".

"children" is usually an array of Objects containing a String "kind" and Object "data":

```
"children": [ { "kind": "t3", "data": {} } ...]
```

I've been handling these fine. My problem is that, sometimes, children will be a simple String array:

```
"children": [ "e78i3mq", "e78hees", "e78jq6q" ]
```

When parsing these, GSON throws an exception like the following:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but
>   was STRING at line 1 column 3780 path
>   $[1].data.children[0].data.replies.data.children[0].data.replies.data.children[0].data.replies.data.children[0].data.children[0]

How can I handle these String array cases?

Comment: is there a another class above it for the 2nd data set? like parent: {children:[]}? You could also store the second one into another variable.

Comment: All children come from a data object, so the data object must be able to handle both types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, thanks for leading me in the right direction Emre!

I ended up getting GsonBuilder to work with a custom method, getGsonAdaptedData.

After retrieving the JSON response in a background thread:

```
...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, (JsonDeserializer<Data>) (arg0, arg1, arg2) -> {
        JsonObject dataJsonObject = arg0.getAsJsonObject();
        Data data = new Gson().fromJson(dataJsonObject, Data.class);
        return RedditUtils.getGsonAdaptedData(dataJsonObject.get("children").getAsJsonArray(), data);
    }).create();
    final Feed responseSubredditFeed = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Feed.class);
...
```

RedditUtils.getGsonAdaptedData

```
// JSON returned for Reddit comments can contain two types of arrays named "children"
// This method checks to see if we were given a Children array or String array
// JSON member "replies" is similar, and can be found in the Data of some Children
// If the method finds a nested "children" array, it recursively adapts its Data
public static Data getGsonAdaptedData(JsonArray childrenJsonArray, Data data) {

    if (childrenJsonArray.size() > 0) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        if (childrenJsonArray.get(0).isJsonObject()) {

            data.setChildrenList(gson.fromJson(childrenJsonArray,
                    new TypeToken<List<Children>>() {
                    }.getType()));

            // Loops through every Data object in the array looking for children and replies
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenJsonArray.size(); i++) {

                JsonObject nestedDataJsonObject = childrenJsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsJsonObject();

                if (nestedDataJsonObject.has("children")) {
                    getGsonAdaptedData(nestedDataJsonObject.get("children").getAsJsonArray(), data.getChildren().get(i).getData());

                } else if (nestedDataJsonObject.has("replies") && nestedDataJsonObject.get("replies").isJsonObject()) {

                    data.getChildren().get(i).getData().setRepliesObject(gson.fromJson(nestedDataJsonObject.get("replies"),
                            new TypeToken<Replies>() {
                            }.getType()));

                    getGsonAdaptedData(nestedDataJsonObject.get("replies").getAsJsonObject().get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("children").getAsJsonArray(), data.getChildren().get(i).getData());
                }
            }
        } else {

            data.setRepliesList(gson.fromJson(childrenJsonArray,
                    new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
                    }.getType()));
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the same endpoint is returning a different type in some instances I suggest wrapping that part in an object and using a deserializer to check the type and assign accordingly. You can do something like this:

```
public Parent serialize(String jsonString) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(WrappedChild.class, new ChildDeserializer());
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, Parent.class);
}

class Parent {
    public List<WrappedChild> children;
}

class ObjectChild {
    public String body;
}

class WrappedChild {
    public ObjectChild objectChild;
    public String stringChild;
}

class ChildDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<WrappedChild> {
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public WrappedChild deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json != null) {
            if (json.isJsonObject()) {
                WrappedChild result = new WrappedChild();
                result.objectChild = gson.fromJson(json, ObjectChild.class);
                return result;
            } else if (json.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                WrappedChild result = new WrappedChild();
                result.stringChild = json.getAsString();
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null; // Or throw new Exception("Unknown child type");
    }
}
```

If you are using retrofit just pass the Gson created by the builder to `GsonConverterFactory.create` as a parameter when creating your service.

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully study [answer from Emre Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674416/6413377) because that way you will have a total control of deserializing. I will just give an another approach which in some cases might require less effort. It bases on the "basic intelligence" of `Gson` deserializing.

If you declare your class that contains `children` like:

```
public class Parent {
    Collection<?> children;
}
```

`Gson` tries its best to "guess" the object type. If it faces a simple string it will be deserialized to a `String`. If it faces data like in your 1st `Json` example, it will deserialized to `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` which is just a `Java` version of `Json` tree.

So depending on how complex is the `data` object in your 1st example and how you use the result overall you might not need to write custom deserializers (which anyway might be better solution eventually).